# When passing a component to the app.js file in react, it compiles but the browser keeps loading and doesnt show anything

Tags: reactjs

This is the app.js code.

[image]

This is the Footer component file code.

[image]

Comment: Per the community guidelines, you should refrain from posting images of code : `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.` - refer to the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You cannot add component directly inside router , please check fundamental documentations then apply something

Answer (score 0):

In React.Component you only initialize the state with 'state=...' once, in constructor. So remove the state={} from your components. If you want to change the initial state, use setState().

Comment: I tried removing "state=" from the footer component but it didnt work. Also, ive tried changing the Footer class into a function instead. Got the same result.